How do I build PCL with VCPKG without it defining PCL_ONLY_CORE_POINT_TYPES
The CMakeLists.txt in the .\vcpkg\buildtrees\pcl\src\pcl-1.13.1-38090574eb.clean folder defines PCL_ONLY_CORE_POINT_TYPES by default, for both MSVC and MINGW. But I need to build PCL for all point types.
If I edit the CMakeLists.txt file to remove the declaration...
  add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNOMINMAX ${SSE_DEFINITIONS}")
  #add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNOMINMAX -DPCL_ONLY_CORE_POINT_TYPES ${SSE_DEFINITIONS}")


...and run VCPKG using the --editable option...
.\vcpkg install pcl[vtk]:x64-windows --featurepackages --recurse --editable pcl


...I get the following build error...
-- Configuring x64-windows
-- Building x64-windows-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
    Command failed: C:/dev/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.27.1-windows/cmake-3.27.1-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j17
    Working Directory: C:/dev/vcpkg/buildtrees/pcl/x64-windows-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      C:\dev\vcpkg\buildtrees\pcl\install-x64-windows-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  ports/pcl/portfile.cmake:74 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:168 (include)

How do I get around this problem?

You did not post install-x64-windows-dbg-out.log mentioned in the error message, so I can't say for sure, but it might be that there are too many symbols to handle for the MSVC linker. Related: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/5928
Why do you need to build PCL for all point types? I.e. which point type do you need that is not contained in the library otherwise? Using #define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE might be a solution for you.

Thanks @IBitMyBytes, defining PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE did the trick. This should be highlighted in bold on the PLC github page or Compiling PCL from source on Windows with a note stating that it should be used if other, non-standard point types are required!
To answer your query about why I needed to build PCL for all point types... I was trying to build the Difference of Normals Based Segmentation example to try to identify linear features - i.e. powerlines - which are excluded by most noise reducing algorithms.
To explain, new multi-pulse scanners are great for increased point density, at the expense of clarity, as they introduce a lot of noise; approximately 1/3 of the data is noise. Unfortunately, the proprietary software used to remove this noise also removes the powerlines, which have very low intensity and very few strikes. It also removes a lot of vegetation, but that's another problem to tackle. :-)
The image below shows the scope of the noise, with the powerlines clearly identifiable.
Powerlines amongst heavy noise

Thanks for the explanation. Sounds like an interesting application :)
